# What can someone access on my device if they have set up iCloud?

Tags: ios, icloud

My dad has given me an iPhone 5s and he has set up iCloud on it. Which he may access. Will he know about whatever I do?

If yes is it possible for me to stop this without him knowing about it? I am using an iPhone for the first time.

Comment: Go to iCloud settings in Settings, turn everything off except for Find My iPhone - which can be useful sometimes. Anything that is turned off cannot be seen by him and everything that is turned on can be seen as him. AFAIK, this is the only setting that sets what you can see from iCloud.

Comment: @shub that's not what he's asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to iCloud.com and login to check what can be seen. (Or don't you have access yourself to it?) Why did he login **your** iPhone? Couldn't you ask him to log out?

To summarize iCloud.com and what can be seen there:

- Contacts (if you set them in iCloud via your iPhone)
- iCal Calendar (if you set them in iCloud via your iPhone)
- Email (if activated) - this will be an @icloud.com or @me.com address
- Notes (if you set them in iCloud via your iPhone)
- Reminders (To do stuff)
- Find My iPhone (NEVER ever turn this off, except if you've sold your iPhone)
- Documents saved in iCloud via Pages, Numbers and Keynote